# An 'in-your-face' (physically) synonym?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

The setting is at a restaurant table/booth and I'm trying to describe a hanging lamp/candle/ornament/chandelier that is basically in the character's face.

The first word that came to my mind was *overbearing*, but I'm guessing it's more of a personality trait than an actual physical adjective. Even *in-your-face* synonyms all seem related to attitude.

Should I say *overwhelming*? *Larger than life*? If you have any suggestions, let me know please!

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a single word?  What's wrong with how you've described it here: *literally / physically in his face*?

Comment: This post lacks research results.

Comment: @TrevorD, it doesn't have to be a single word, but literally/physically/basically don't really have the strong negative/unwelcome connotation that I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You could describe the lamp as *[obtrusive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obtrusive)*.

> noticeable in an unpleasant or annoying way

*"The obtrusive lamp blocked his view."*

Comment: Or the somewhat stronger intrusive. Please add some citations to your answer. One liners aren't typically well received here.